# Invalid chart type given box

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Here is my code

```
    from pandas import read_csv
    from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
    from matplotlib import pyplot

    filename = 'iris.data.csv'
    names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'class']
    dataset = read_csv(filename, names=names)
    print(dataset.shape)
    print(dataset.head(20))

    # Data visualizations
    dataset.plot(kind='box', subplots=True, layout=(2,2), sharex=False, sharey=False)
    pyplot.show()
```

When i run above code. Then following error is shown

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/k/UBUNTU2/Work and stuff/coding language/Python/Machine learning/exp.py", line 43, in <module>
    dataset.plot(kind='box', subplots=True, layout=(2,2), sharex=False, sharey=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 2090, in plot_frame
    raise ValueError('Invalid chart type given %s' % kind)
ValueError: Invalid chart type given box
```

Any idea ? What should i do? Please help

Comment: What version of pandas do you use?

Comment: pandas : 0.14.0

Answer (score 1):

Your pandas version (0.14) is already 3 years old. The "box" kind was introduced in version 0.15. Now we are at version 0.20.

The solution is thus to install a newer version of pandas in order to be able to use `kind="box"` in the plotting wrapper.

If you need to use version 0.14 you can get boxplot using the [`DataFrame.boxplot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.0/visualization.html#visualization-box) method. The usage according to documentation would be:

```
df = DataFrame(rand(10,5))
plt.figure();
bp = df.boxplot()
```